# Typedef declaration with squared brackets

Tags: c, typedef

What does this expression mean:

```
typedef char foo [FOO];
```

I am just struggeling with the meaning of the expression between the squared brackets.

Comment: Do you know what `char foo[8]` means?

Comment: yes, in this case foo is an array with 8 items, right?

Comment: Yeah, and in a typedef, foo is the *type* of an array with 8 items. You can then do `foo   a;` to make `a` an array (and to confuse everyone about that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It reads `foo` is the type of an array of `FOO`-many `char` elements. In this case, `FOO` is a constant, defined somewhere as `#define FOO 100`

```
typedef int pair[2]; // Pair is an array of two ints.
```

Comment: yes but how can an array have FOO-many elements, while FOO is a string not an integer

Comment: @Maxi Search your code for `#define FOO 100` or some other integer literal. If you can't find it normally, run the code through the preprocessor (`gcc -E source.c`) and see how it is defined. FOO is replaced with the number before compiling the source.

Comment: @Maxi Really? I doubt it. If `FOO` is truly a string, show it in the question, you must know its definition somewhere.

Comment: you are right, it is defined somewhere else using the #define FOO x expression, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

C Typedefs have the basic form `typedef...type-declaration...` *name-of-type*

In this case the name of the type is "foo"

The type itself is a char array with size FOO.

The confusing part is that the brackets are *after* the name, so in sense the declaration is on both sides of the symbol which will represent the type. This is a quirk of array declarations which can have the brackets after their name. So, in this case the syntax is like this:

`typedef...type-declaration...` *name-of-type*[ (optional constant) ]

If you look in the original The [C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) in the back, the relevant part reads like this:

> type-name:
>        type-specifier abstract-declarator
>
> abstract-declarator:
>        empty
>        ( abstract-declarator )
>        * abstract-declarator
>        abstract-declarator ()
>        abstract-declarator [ constant-expression<sub>opt</sub> ]

where a type-specifier can be things like `char`, `int` or `typedef` (as in this case). The last of the 5 kinds of abstract-declarators is the array declarator which has the brackets after it. Note that it is recursive; so an *abstract-declarator* can be a pointer to an *abstract-declarator* and so on and so forth.

Comment: "C Typedefs have the basic form `typedef...type-declaration...` *name-of-type*" - this is a very simplistic (and incorrect) view of typedefs.  For example, `typedef int *(*(*fptr)(void))[N])` creates `fptr` as a type name for "pointer to function returning pointer to N-element array of pointer to `int`".  Syntactically, the `typedef` keyword is treated as a storage class qualifier; stick it in front of *any* declaration, and what would have been the identifier in the declarator becomes the typedef name.

Comment: @JohnBode That is why it says the BASIC form of a typedef, not the form of a typedef. I have added the grammar description from K&R to describe the full range of different possibilities. Often when trying to understand something, you want to start with the simplest case and work from there, not throw the full complexity at the student up front.

Comment: This is, interestingly, still very much incomplete, because this is a valid typedef: `unsigned typedef char UCHAR;`. Though I agree most people should only work with the most basic version. :)